# Laravel Eloquent event inheritance

Tags: inheritance, laravel, subclass, eloquent

When I do this:

```
class Content extends Eloquent {

}

Content::saving(function($content) {
    // do something
});

class Article extends Content {

}
```

The 'do something' event doesn't fire when saving an Article. Is there any way that Article can inherit this event binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [late static binding](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/php-5-3-feature-late-static-binding) in the parent's static `boot` method that laravel automatically calls:

```php
class Content extends Eloquent
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model) {
            // do something
        });
    }

}
```